# Menus not showing up on older apis

Tags: java, android, menu, android-appcompat

I have an application which works fine on apis 4.0+ but on older apis menus are not showing up. I use the last version of the appcompat library.

Activity :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Fragments :

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.interval_timer, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_interval_training"
        android:title="@string/action_interval_training"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_advanced_session"
        android:title="@string/action_advanced_session"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Thank you

EDIT : it seems that it doesnt work only if i set showAsAction="never" ...

Comment: Does your activity extend `Activity` or `ActionBarActivity`?

Comment: it extends ActionBarActivity

Comment: I wonder if appcompat v21 is intended to work on pre-ICS devices

Comment: @andryr it is, that's why it is called `appcompat-v7` which means backwards-compatibility down to Android 2.1

Answer (score 0):

On devices with a hardware menu key (such as all Gingerbread devices), that hardware button is still used to trigger the overflow menu - where all items with `showAsAction="never"` appear.